# Allow mongoDB to save duplicate emails with 'unique: true'

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose

I'd like to be able to allow admins to use a single email and have multiple user names (bypassing the unique constraint for email). Moreover, if users aren't admins then they can't bypass the unique constraint.

However, using `partialFilterExpression` I thought this was the route to go using the roles I have defined (`user` and `admin`) but every time I save a new admin user, then when I try to add another admin user with another username (same email) I get the error:

```
E11000 duplicate key error collection: convofinddb.users index: email_1 dup key: { email: "email@gmail.com" }
```

## User Schema

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    firstName: {},
    lastName: {},
    userName: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      unique: true,
    },
    email: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      index: {
        unique: true,
        partialFilterExpression: { role: { $eq: 'user' } },
      },
    },
    password: {},
    role: {
      type: String,
      enum: ['admin', 'user'],
      default: 'user',
    },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true
  }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Would you show the code that tries to create a new `role: "admin"` and also show all the indexes on the collection?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I figured it out

- I'll need to check if a user's role is an `admin`
- If an admin, create a new user
- Then create another email index using `partialFilterExpression` and `{ unique: false }`

```
// this data would be from some form...
const userBody = {
  firstName: 'John',
  lastName: 'Doe',
  userName: 'welit9000',
  email: 'email@gmail.com',
  password: '****',
  confirmPassword: '****',
  role: 'admin'
}

if (userBody.role === 'admin') {
  const user = await UserModel.create(userBody);

  await UserModel.collection.createIndex({ email: 1 }, { unique: false, partialFilterExpression: { role: { $eq: 'admin' } } });
      
}
```